# Expressing a solution in interval notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, notation

I am faced with this problem. I am told to express the answer in interval notation.

```
|3x| > 12
```

I solve like usual, by doing this:

```
3x > 12  3x < -12

x > 4  x < -4
```

My problem is how would I express this in interval notation. I know that if it were x < 4 x > -4 it would be (-4, 4), but on a graph their solution sets point in opposite directions. I don't know where it starts or ends. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

$x\in (-\infty,-4)\cup(4,+\infty)$ is a an option. It is a union of two disjoint intervals.

There is no way of writing it as one interval.